100vh div has half page height when printing pdf
I set the div to be 100vh but when printing it's only half of the page. I tried adding media print but without changes. I've also tried to set height to 100% instead. In HTML works but not on pdf.


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.page100vh {
  background-color: red;
  height: 1000vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media print {
  .page100vh {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
<div class="page100vh"></div>





How are you generating this PDF? Are you using a library or the generic (built-in) PDF printer in your OS?

@DarkBee It's inside a CRM but I don't know which library it uses. It ignores vh and it conder it to be 550px. It does not consider the viewport to be the A4 pdf page.

When defining objects in a PDF the units should be similar for X & Y (PDF is technically unitless). Thus best to use px for HTML. however we can use inches or mm for the media ratio such as 210 x 297 for A4.
The division to fully cover that page may be described as 100% of width thus in height that should be 141.421% same width units and for 2 pages it will be 282.842% of width. vh is not tied to vw for PDF /MediaBox viewport scale is only useful for a HTML screen.


@media print {
@page { size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}
}
html,
body {

  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.pageDiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 141.421vw;
  width: 100vw;
}
<div class="pageDiv">Hello World!</div>





